# Is there a reason behind the "wrong" German localizations of English movies/TV shows

Tags: dialogue, translation

I live in a German speaking country but prefer watching movies/TV shows in English. The biggest reason is, in my opinion, the wrong translation of the word "you". In German there are two possible translations:

- "Sie": formal, usually used when talking to an adult in a business relation or a child talking to an adult or talking to elderly people. In addition this is mostly combined with the family name: "Sie, Herr Schmied" = "You, Mr. Smith"
- "Du": informal, between children and friends, though in many companies nowadays also between coworkers. In addition this is mostly combined with the given name. "Du, Michael" = "You, Michael"

In German localizations "Sie" is used most of the time. And this just doesn't make sense to me. Like, I would never use "Sie" on a date or rarely someone at my age (mid 30s) I meet on the street. This was maybe common 50 years ago, but not today. With business customers it somehow is still expected, even if I don't like it.
In my experience with communicating with US residents, the family name is rarely used and in emails the given name is used. Maybe I make a wrong link here and using he given name is considered formal in the US.

**Is "Sie" the right translation for "you" in informal conversation (in movies/TV shows)?**

Comment: *"I would never use "Sie" [for] someone at my age (mid 30s) I meet on the street."* - Well, I certainly would. I'd never downright "you" someone I haven't ever met unless it's clearly a minor (or I work in a stupid Apple Store). So this seems quite down to subjective impression. That being said, the question (especially the actual bold part) might be more appropriate for [german.se], since it doesn't seem that related to movies & TV at all.

Comment: Lucky you, I am from a country doesn't speak English too and most of the times someone "presumably" speak my native language, I don't understand anything he's saying, also the tv channels translate it as it's a foreign language so it's not just me who don't understand it if you're wondering

Comment: @NapoleonWilson ok, never is probably to harsh. But let's say you see a pretty lady and after some eye contact you want to talk to her, would you use "Sie"? And the bold part like I wrote it woudl fit in German Language. I'm thinking how to rephrase this to be more fitting here as I'm mainly interested why they synchronize it like that.

Comment: @Thomas *"But let's say you see a pretty lady and after some eye contact you want to talk to her, would you use "Sie"?"* - That highly depends on the situation and the surroundings. But we're digressing, I guess.

Comment: I've once read that translating English 'you' into languages that have a T-V distinction (a formal grammatical person) is one of the hardest tasks the translators deal with. This is because in many situations it's rather vague whether a formal form should be used or not (and your discussion with Napoleon Wilson seems to confirm that). Additionally sometimes the translator doesn't have the complete information regarding the familiarity of the speakers. Based on that it's not surprising that the translation can often be considered incorrect.

Comment: @Tautologist But if a translator just translates the words, it is a bad translator. I would expect a translator watching the movie/show first in the original language to get a feeling for the characters. Or even better, the script is annotated by the author to show the familiarity between the characters.

Comment: @Thomas - I'd bet the translator never saw the scene, let alone the full context; it's a job, they do it, they get paid. Also, the original author/actor/director simply never ***cared*** how a language with 'little you/big you' differentiation might envisage it - it's hard to imagine something that simply does not exist in your own language/culture.

Comment: @Tetsujin Uh...I don't think so. You can't dub a movie that you haven't seen at all. You might have a wrong understanding of how dubbing is really done here.